# Скрипт для поиска блоков в Minecraft Bedrock Edition

Tags: java, minecraft

Задача написать скрипт на Java, который будет читать уровень Minecraft Bedrock Edition и находить координаты определенных видов блоков.

Проблема с чтением карты Minecraft Bedrock Edition (файл .mcworld).

Данные об уровне лежат в файле level.dat и в папке db

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Погуглил, выяснил, что данные об уровне именно в Minecraft Bedrock Edition хранятся в NBT (Named Binary Tag) формате.

Но не могу разобраться, как можно считать данные об уровне, а именно, где, какие блоки расположены.

Писать свой декодер не очень хочется да и это не нужно скорее всего.

Конвертировать Minecraft Bedrock Edition в Minecraft Java Edition нежелательно. Хочется работать именно с Minecraft Bedrock Edition.

Может, кто-то подскажет, как прочитать данные.

Пример уровня, который хочу прочитать здесь:
https://disk.yandex.ru/d/zPjyNZIJJ1ravA

Comment: https://github.com/Darkhax/OpenNBT